# Make class instance saveable with NSUserDefaults Swift

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I'm quite new to programming iOS-Apps and Swift. I tried to save a class instance of a custom class to `NSUserDefaults` but when when I try to restore the saved data from the storage I receive `nil`.
I can't find my mistake and I don't know where it could hide, so I'll post all the related code blocks underneath. Thanks for helping! :)

That's my code:

```
class Note: NSObject, NSCoding{

    var note: Int?
    var position: Int?
    var fach: String?
    var fachtyp: String?

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.note = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("note") as? Int
        self.position = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("position") as? Int
        self.fach = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("fach") as? String
        self.fachtyp = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("fachtyp") as? String
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.note, forKey: "note")
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.position, forKey: "position")
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.fach, forKey: "fach")
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.fachtyp, forKey: "fachtyp")
    }
}
```

```
class Fach: NSObject, NSCoding{
    var fachNoten: [Note] = []
    init(fachNoten: [Note]){
        self.fachNoten = fachNoten
        super.init()
    }


    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.fachNoten = (aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("fachNoten") as? [Note])!
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.fachNoten, forKey: "fachNoten")
    }

}
```

```
var hallo1 = [Fach(fachNoten: [])]
var hallo2 = [Fach(fachNoten: [])]
var gesamtarray: [String: [Fach]] = ["Hallo1": hallo1, "Hallo2": hallo2]
var testarray: [String: [Fach]] = [:]

func save() {
    let savedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(gesamtarray)
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setObject(savedData, forKey: "gesamtarray")
    _ = defaults.synchronize()
}

func restore() {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if let savedData = defaults.objectForKey("gesamtarray") as? NSData {
        testarray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(savedData) as! [String: [Fach]]
    }
    else {
        print("Couldn't save")
    }
}
```

Comment: What's `nil` exactly?

Comment: Actually you need an initializer to be able to assign values to the properties in the class `Note` before saving them. An optional is `nil` by default. Try to use non-optionals as much as possible. At least `note` and `fach` seem to be required to have a value.

Comment: Also, consider using Core Data for this. NSUserDefaults is not supposed to store objects like this, if you need persistence you need a database.

Comment: Save yourself some serious headache trying to do something that's not really good practice, and look at something like Realm [link](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) Its very lightweight and super easy to implement.